# Bison how to return a pointer in parse tree

Tags: c++, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, bison, parse-tree

I'm trying to create a AST with Bison. I am having issues getting bison to return a pointer of the node `var` - after an identifier is found.

Here's the error:

```
Error   C2664   'VarDel::VarDel(VarDel &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Var' to 'Node *'
```

Here's a snippet from the Bison file:

```
%union {
    Node *node;
    Block *block;
    //NExpression *expr;
    //NStatement *stmt;
    Statement *stmt;
    Num *num;
    Var *ident;
    VarDel *var_decl;
    std::string *string;
    int token;
}


%token <string> TIDENTIFIER TINTEGER TDOUBLE
%token <token> TCEQ TCNE TCLT TCLE TCGT TCGE TEQUAL
%token <token> TLPAREN TRPAREN TLBRACE TRBRACE TCOMMA TDOT
%token <token> TPLUS TMINUS TMUL TDIV


%type <ident> ident
%type <num> numeric num 
%type <block> program block stmts
%type <node> stmt var_decl
%type <token> comparison

...

var_decl : ident ident { $$ = new VarDel(*$1, *$2); }
         ;

ident : TIDENTIFIER { $$ = new Var($1->c_str()); delete $1; }
      ;
```

And heres the involved node classes:

```
class VarDel : public Node {
public:
    Node* typenode;
    Node* varnode;
    Node* assignNode;

    VarDel(Node* ctypenode, Node* cvarnode) {
        Node::nodeType = NODETYPE::VARDEL;
        typenode = ctypenode;
        varnode = cvarnode;
    }
    VarDel(Node* ctypenode, Node* cvarnode, Node* cassignnode) {
        Node::nodeType = NODETYPE::VARDEL;
        typenode = ctypenode;
        varnode = cvarnode;
        assignNode = cassignnode;
    }
    std::string toString() {
        return "VarDel Node";
    }
};

class Var : public Node {
public:
    std::string identfier;
    Var();
    Var(std::string cidentfier) {
        Node::nodeType = NODETYPE::VAR;
        identfier = cidentfier;
    }
    std::string toString() {
        return "Var Node";
    }
};
```

Why am I getting this error? Surely I am creating a pointer from `ident` with the `new` keyword?

Comment: `ident` gets translated to a `Var *`. When you work out, on paper and pencil, the actual types of arguments to the constructor of the object you're `new`ing, what results do you get?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry, I don't understand your point, could you elaborate? If `ident` is being translated to `Var*` why am I receiving such an error? Thanks

Comment: Which line does the error refer to? What are the semantic types declared for your various non-terminals?

Comment: My bad I forgot to update the error message after I got rid of one of the constructors of Var.. I have updated the post

Comment: @rici I have update the post with the semantics

Comment: That error now makes complete sense to me. You call the `VarDel` constructor with `*$1`; `$1` is an `ident` whose semantic type is `Var*`, so the type of `*$1` is `Var`. But the constructor is expecting a `Var*`. So why the dereference in the constructor call?

Comment: @rici thanks so much, I completely missed this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys

```
var_decl : ident ident { $$ = new VarDel($1, $2); }
         ;                               ^   ^

ident : TIDENTIFIER { $$ = new Var($1->c_str()); delete $1; }
      ;
```